Poetry не собирает проект
У меня есть vds с rocky linux 9.4 на борту, там используется питон версии 3.9 и обновить его не выйдет (вроде как)
Я стягиваю с гитхаба проект, написанный на питоне 3.11, пробую poetry install и получаю
The currently activated Python version 3.9.18 is not supported by the project (^3.11).
Trying to find and use a compatible version. 

Poetry was unable to find a compatible version. If you have one, you can explicitly use it via the "env use" command.


почему poetry не может установить питон 3.11 в venv?
как заставить проект собираться и работать?


poetry не устанавливает python вообще. Вам нужно самостоятельно установить python либо вручную, либо через pyenv (например), на интерпретатор нужной версии установить poetry, и через него уже запускать проект. Жизнь-боль.

@insolor а в мире питона есть альтернатива поетри, которая еще и версии япа подтягивает?

Обновлять предустановленный на системе python не нужно (так можно вообще систему сломать). Вполне можно отдельно установить рядом другую версию.

Ну pyenv может устанавливать и "активировать" разные версии python, но у меня на Linux Mint он не хочет работать нормально, ну и в целом он не альтернатива poetry. Больше ничего такого похожего не знаю.

@insolor мне скорее альтернатива нпм нужна, но для питона) все из коробки, без заморочек, красота

Нет такого. У poetry есть альтернативы (разной степени сырости), но ни одна из них не умеет разные версии python устанавливать, насколько я знаю.

На macos получается комбинировать pyenv + poetry, на linux мне приходится из deadsnakes разные версии python ставить.



почему poetry не может установить питон 3.11 в венв?


Poetry не умеет устанавливать python. Из известных мне утилит только pyenv умеет это делать (но на Linux мне не удалось его завести). Но pyenv умеет только устанавливать разные версии python и переключать между ними, альтернативой poetry он не является.


как заставить проект собираться и работат?


Установить дополнительный интерпретатор python нужной версии любым способом (ни в коем случае не заменять системный).
После этого poetry должен сам увидеть эту версию, при выполнении команды poetry install напишет что-то такое (тестирую на своем проекте, у вас номера версий будут другими):
The currently activated Python version 3.9.19 is not supported by the project (^3.10).
Trying to find and use a compatible version. 
Using python3 (3.10.12)
...

Если poetry сам не нашел нужную версию, то используйте команду
poetry env use python3.11

Вместо python3.11 пробуйте указать полный путь к интерпретатору. Это создаст виртуальное окружение с этим интерпретатором. Далее устанавливаете проект и его зависимости в это окружение командой poetry install.
Далее можно будет запустить проект, как именно — по идее должно быть описано в readme проекта.
